# Windows 7 system won't talk to MIT Kerberos server

Tags: windows, kerberos, mitkerberos

I've installed MIT Kerberos 1.10 on a Debian server and happily have my Debian clients authenticating with it. I'm having some trouble getting my Windows 7 machine to do the same, however.

I've used `ksetup` to configure the machine as follows:

```
default realm = EXAMPLE.COM (external)
EXAMPLE.COM:
        (no kdc entries for this realm)
        Realm Flags = 0x5 SendAddress Delegate
Mapping all users (*) to a local account by the same name (*).
```

This also changed the system's name and workgroup settings:

```
Computer name: lysander
Full computer name: lysander.EXAMPLE.COM
Workgroup EXAMPLE.COM
```

According to the documentation, if there are no KDC or password entries for a realm, Windows will use the DNS, so I also have the following entries configured:

```
_kerberos._udp.example.com. 300 SRV 10 100 88 kdc.example.com.
_kerberos-adm._tcp.example.com. 300 SRV 10 100 749 kdc.example.com.
```

`kdc` has an A record that points at the server's IP address.

After configuring the Windows system I rebooted it and tried to log in, noting that the login screen offered to log me into the `EXAMPLE` domain. However, when I attempt to log in as the local user `sam`, which should  be mapped to `sam@EXAMPLE.COM`, after a brief pause I am told that there are no logon servers available to service the logon request. I can't see anything relevant in the Windows event log, and having examined the network traffic between the client and the server, I can't even see that the Windows machine is trying to contact the KDC.

It's not all bad news, however. What gives me hope is that I can use `runas` to get a `TGT`:

```
>runas /user:sam@EXAMPLE.COM cmd
Enter the password for sam@EXAMPLE.COM:
Attempting to start cmd as user "sam@EXAMPLE.COM" ...
```

And in the new window that appears:

```
>klist

Current LogonId is 0:0x14e6649

Cached Tickets: (1)

#0>     Client: sam @ EXAMPLE.COM
        Server: krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM @ EXAMPLE.COM
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40e10000 -> forwardable renewable initial pre_authent name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 2/14/2012 11:54:24 (local)
        End Time:   2/14/2012 21:54:24 (local)
        Renew Time: 2/21/2012 11:54:24 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
```

If I then launch PuTTY from that command prompt, I can ssh into the other servers using SSPI to authenticate just fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that if I enter the full username `sam@EXAMPLE.COM` at the Windows  screen then logging on works fine; `sam` or `EXAMPLE\sam` don't cut the mustard. I can't find anything that confirms that this is the expected behaviour, but it is consistent with a careful reading of the output of `ksetup`:

```
Mapping all users (*) to a local account by the same name (*).
```

i.e., if you log in as `sam@EXAMPLE.COM` then the local account `sam` will be logged in; this does not imply that you can log in as `sam` and have the system authenticate you with the KDC as `sam@EXAMPLE.COM`.